# Find $\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}ke^{-kx^2}\arctan(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Find $\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}ke^{-kx^2}\arctan(x)dx$.

I think that the limit is infinity.

$ke^{-kx^2}\leq ke^{-kx^2}\arctan(x)$ for $[\tan(1),\infty)$, but by integrating we know that $\int_{0}^{\infty}ke^{-kx^2}\to \infty$ and so out sequence of original integrals diveres too.

Is this correct?

Comment: @Tavish What is the point you're trying to make?

Comment: Have you tried a by parts integration.

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty}ke^{-kx^2} dx=(\pi k )^{\frac{1}{2}}$ thus I think you are right.

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini Your conclusion is not correct.  See my posted solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enforce the substitution $x=t/\sqrt{k}$.  Then, we can write
$$\int_0^\infty ke^{-kx^2}\arctan(x)\,dx= \int_0^\infty \sqrt{k} e^{-t^2}\arctan(t/\sqrt{k})\,dt$$

---

Now, $\arctan(x)\le x$ for $x\ge 0$, so that $\left|\sqrt{k} e^{-t^2}\arctan(t/\sqrt{k})\right|\le te^{-t^2}$.

---

Inasmuch as $\int_0^\infty te^{-t^2}\,dt<\infty$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_0^\infty \sqrt{k} e^{-t^2}\arctan(t/\sqrt{k})\,dt&=\int_0^\infty \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{k} e^{-t^2}\arctan(t/\sqrt{k})\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty te^{-t^2}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$
And we are done!

---

> **NOTE:  Analyzing the argument in the OP**

The OP observed correctly that for $x\in [\tan(1),\infty)$, $\arctan(x)>1$.

However, the integral $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{\tan(1)}^\infty ke^{-kx^2}\,dx\ne \infty$.

To see this, simply note that $ke^{-kx^2}\le \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $\int_{\tan(1)}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx=\cot(1)$.

However, the $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^{\tan(1)}ke^{-kx^2}\,dx=\infty$.

But for $x\in [0,\tan(1)]$, $\arctan(x)$ does not behave like a constant.  Rather, it has a small argument approximation $\arctan(x)\sim x$. And clearly $\int_0^{\tan(1) }kx e^{-kx^2}\,dx$ converges as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: What a brilliant answer .

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain me, after I proved that $\int_0^{\infty} te^{-t^2} dt < \infty$ as you did, why is wrong to take the limit of the initial integral $\int_0^{\infty} \lim_{k \to \infty} ke^{-kx^2} \arctan x dx$ and instead I have to take necessarily the limit of $\int_0^{\infty} \lim_{k \to \infty} \sqrt{k}e^{-t^2} \arctan \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{k}}\right) dt=\frac{1}{2}$? Thank you.

Comment: @ZaWarudo The DCT does not apply in the case you presented.  And we cannot justify the interchange of the limit and the integral.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error and giving the proper solution. I erroneously thought the problem with integrability is at infinity not near the origin. The substitution was splendid!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.